# Javascript es6 combine 2 static classes into an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having this code:

```
class A {
   static b() {

   }
}

class B {
  static c() {

  }
}
```

I am trying to combine these 2 static classes into one:

```
const combined = { ...A, ...B };
```

However, the combined object results in an empty one while I am expecting an object containing all the static methods combined.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you trying to define the static methods at a new object?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am trying to achieve, define the static methods inside the new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of the static methods of a class with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`:

```js
class A {
  static staticMethod() {}
  nonStaticMethod() {}
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A));
```

There are a few properties we are not interested in, namely `prototype`, `length` and `name`. We can filter them out manually, e.g. like this:

```js
class A {
  static staticMethod() {}
  nonStaticMethod() {}
}

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A)
    .filter(prop => prop !=='prototype' && prop !== 'length' && prop !== 'name')
);
```

Good! Now we can create the `combined` object and add `A`'s filtered methods to it:

```js
class A {
  static b() {
    console.log('called A.b');
  }
}

const classAMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A)
                        .filter(prop => prop !== 'prototype' &&
                                        prop !== 'length' &&
                                        prop !== 'name');

const combined = {};
combined.A = {};

classAMethods.forEach(method => {
  combined.A[method] = () => A[method]();
});

console.log(combined);
combined.A.b();
```

If you'd rather like to be able to call `combined.b()`, you can do the following. Note that this way methods with the same name in multiple classes will clash. E.g. if you have both `A.b` and `B.b` defined, `combined` can only hold one of them.

```js
class A {
  static b() {
    console.log('called A.b');
  }
}

const classAMethods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(A)
                        .filter(prop => prop !== 'prototype' &&
                                        prop !== 'length' &&
                                        prop !== 'name');

const combined = {};

classAMethods.forEach(method => {
  combined[method] = () => A[method]();
});

console.log(combined);
combined.b();
```

To bring all together, we have the following. Note that I used `...args` to add support for passing arguments when calling the class methods.

```js
class A {
  static b() {
    console.log('called A.b');
  }
}

class B {
  static c(name1, name2) {
    console.log('called B.c, hello', name1, 'and', name2);
    return 'returned by B.c';
  }
}


const getMethods = (cls) => Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cls)
                              .filter(prop => prop !== 'prototype' &&
                                              prop !== 'length' &&
                                              prop !== 'name');

const combined = {};

const addMethodsToCombined = (cls) => {
  combined[cls.name] = {};
  getMethods(cls).forEach(method => {
    combined[cls.name][method] = (...args) => cls[method](...args);
  });
};


addMethodsToCombined(A);
addMethodsToCombined(B);

console.log(combined);
combined.A.b();
console.log(combined.B.c('world', 'universe'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

When you add new static methods to class `A` or `B`, they will automatically be available through `combined` as well. If you create a new class `C`, you just need to call `addMethodsToCombined(C)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the methods at a new object

```
const combined = {A:A.b, B:B.c}
```

Comment: I am looking to add additional static ones in future. I wouldn't like to statically place it inside there each time I create a new one.

Comment: Then you can use `let` to define `combined` then use object spread when re-defining `combined` and adding a property `class C {
  static d(){}
}; 
combined = {...combined, C:C.d}`

Answer (score 0):

You could extend B from A, then extend another class from B.

If you're using static classes though, it might be better to just use object literals

```js
class A {
   static b() {
      console.log('called A.b')
   }
}

class B extends A {
  static c() {
    console.log('called B.c')
  }
}

class Combined extends B {}

Combined.b()
Combined.c()
```